# Why isn't Xcode showing my nodes overtime the simulator runs?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have this code in my GameScene swift file:

```
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
let blockImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block")
let blockSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setUpGame()
}
func setUpGame(){
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(background)

    let block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockImage, size: blockSize)
    block.position.x = block.frame.width/2
    block.position.y = frame.height - block.frame.height/2
addChild(block)
}
```

This is my code in my GameController file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        let scene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
    
        
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
        
        // added to see physics body
        view.showsPhysics =  true
    }
}
```

why does it take multiple runs for my block node to appear on the simulator except for my background? After the block finally show, it will continue to show after every run until I edit my code. Ive tried removing my background node just in case that might be the issue, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Where's the `addChild(block)`?

Comment: @bg2b I forgot to add it in. I just updated it

Comment: @matt yeah and nothing comes up

Comment: Try setting `zPosition` for the block to make sure it’s above the background.